# Call method after certain random interval of time

Tags: c#, winforms

I have 5 methods and I need them to be called after random interval(1 to 3 sec) of time. Say first method is called after 1 sec, then second method is called after 2.3 sec, next method after 1.5 etc. I did following using timer

```
System.Windows.Forms.Timer mytimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();
mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);    
Random rand = new Random();
int fortimerinterval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
mytimer.Interval = fortimerinterval; 
mytimer.Enabled = true;
mytimer.Start();

    public void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
    {
        fortimerinterval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
        mytimer.Interval = fortimerinterval; 
        first time call function1, then call function2
        //this is main theme, so im not giving whole code here


    }
```

But timer interval remain unchanged after it gets first random value. It seems that, timerinterval value don't change for each time TimerEventProcessor is called. How can I do that? Or if there is any other easy way to do this.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've modified your code a bit and tried it. It works allright.

```
Random rand = new Random();
Timer mytimer = new Timer();

private void fireTimerClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    mytimer.Tick += new EventHandler(TimerEventProcessor);
    mytimer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);
    mytimer.Enabled = true;
    mytimer.Start();
}

public void TimerEventProcessor(Object myObject, EventArgs myEventArgs)
{
    mytimer.Interval = rand.Next(1000, 3000);

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now);
}
```

You can verify this with the debug output window. `fireTimerClick` is simply a button click event handler.